# Merging subscription forms into 1

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Instead of asking our clients to subscribe using multiple forms, I am trying to join the forms together with a checkbox option.

Forms for the subscription service have unique Data-ID's, otherwise they are identical.

Form 1:

```
<form class="form" id="subForm" action="https://WEBSITE/LINK/HERE" method="post" data-id="987ZXY">
<label>Email </label>
<input autocomplete="Email" aria-label="Email" id="fieldEmail" maxlength="200" name="form" required="" type="email">
<button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form class="form" id="subForm" action="https://WEBSITE/LINK/HERE" method="post" data-id="123ABC">
<label>Email </label>
<input autocomplete="Email" aria-label="Email" id="fieldEmail" maxlength="200" name="form" required="" type="email">
<button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to allow the user to select what they would like to subscribe to with the checkbox, which would then include the appropriate data-id's before submitting. I am struggling though.
The form submits to a email service provider, which means I am unable to control anything outside of the form submission.

```
<form class="form" id="subForm" action="https://WEBSITE/LINK/HERE" method="post">
<label>Email </label>
<input autocomplete="Email" aria-label="Email" id="fieldEmail" maxlength="200" name="form" required="" type="email">
<h3>Subcribe to the following</h3>
<input type="checkbox" id="987ZXY" name="subscription1" value="987ZXY">
  <label for="subscription1"> Subscription A</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="123ABC" name="subscription2" value="123ABC">
  <label for="subscription2"> Subscription B</label><br>
<button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

When submitting, the form does not work. The data-id element solution is not updating.

Comment: Where is the code that is processing your form though ? And whats not working exactly..

Comment: Hi Pogrindis. The form is submitting to the 3rd party service provider (createsend). The provider dishes out the form with unique data-id's and then submits back to the provider.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in browser form submission that will take a "data-id" from a form so there must be something else submitting.

Note I had to change the label's `for` attribute

You can set the form data-id like this, but you can have only one

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("subForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    const rad = document.querySelector("[name=subscription]:checked");
    if (rad) this.dataset.id = rad.value
    else {
      alert("please select a subscription")
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form class="form" id="subForm" action="https://WEBSITE/LINK/HERE" method="post">
  <label>Email </label>
  <input autocomplete="Email" aria-label="Email" id="fieldEmail" maxlength="200" name="form" required="" type="email">
  <h3>Subcribe to the following</h3>
  <input type="radio" id="subscription1" name="subscription" value="987ZXY">
  <label for="subscription1"> Subscription A</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="Subscription2" name="subscription" value="123ABC">
  <label for="subscription2"> Subscription B</label><br>
  <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

If the submit handler can handle two IDs in the dataid, you can have your checkboxes

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("subForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    const chk = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=subscription]:checked")].map(chk => chk.value);
    if (chk) this.dataset.id = chk.join(", ")
    else {
      alert("please select a subscription")
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form class="form" id="subForm" action="https://WEBSITE/LINK/HERE" method="post">
  <label>Email </label>
  <input autocomplete="Email" aria-label="Email" id="fieldEmail" maxlength="200" name="form" required="" type="email">
  <h3>Subcribe to the following</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" id="subscription1" name="subscription" value="987ZXY">
  <label for="subscription1"> Subscription A</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Subscription2" name="subscription" value="123ABC">
  <label for="subscription2"> Subscription B</label><br>
  <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```